# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table TABLE_JSON

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring boot, H2 database

my requirement is to store json string into database.

below is my entity class

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_JSON")
public class DataJson {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @NonNull
    private String check;

    @NonNull
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    @Convert(converter= JSONObjectConverterForMe.class)
    private JSONObject json_data;

}
```

below is Converter class

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Converter
public class JSONObjectConverterForMe implements AttributeConverter<JSONObject, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(JSONObject jsonData) {
        String json;
        try{
            json = jsonData.toString();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex)
        {
            //extend error handling here if you want
            json = "";
        }
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    public JSONObject convertToEntityAttribute(String jsonDataAsJson) {
        JSONObject jsonData;
        try {
            jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonDataAsJson);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            //extend error handling here if you want
            jsonData = null;
        }
        return jsonData;
    }
}
```

when i run the spring boot application, i got below error

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table TABLE_JSON (id varchar(255) not null, check varchar(255), json_data TEXT, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
```

**below are the complete error details**

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table TABLE_JSON (id varchar(255) not null, check varchar(255), json_data TEXT, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) [spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) [spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) [spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) [spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.spglobal.ratings.rap.modelconfig.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check` is a [SQL Reserved keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp), so you can't use `check` as a column name without quote/backtick.
By default hibernate doesn't use quote/backtick for column name in query. You can use explicitly use backtick/quote this way

```
@Column(name="`check`")
private String check;
```

In some Database, backtick won't work eg: postgresql use quote for them

```
@Column(name="\"check\"")
private String check;
```

Or you can force hibernate to use quote for column and table name using this in config file

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

You should also specify the length of `id` column by default it's 255 which make problem.

```
@Column(name = "id", length = 36 , updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use a SQL-Keyword (`check`) as a column name. Try naming that column differently:

```
@NonNull
@Column(name="another_column_name")
private String check;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Finally I realised. my table name is reserved keyword. **please do not use reserved keyword** in postgresql as **table name, column name**.